# Are constant functions progressive?

Tags: functions

A function $f\in L^2(R)$ is defined as progressive iff its Fourier transform is supported by $[0,\infty)$.

The Fourier transform of a real, non-zero, constant $a$ is:

$$F(a) = a\sqrt{2\pi}\delta(\omega)$$

This function is zero for all values of $\omega$ except $\omega = 0$, which is also in the range $[0,\infty)$. Thus, any real non-zero constant is a progressive function.

Is this correct or not?

If this is correct, why is the definition of a progressive function such that 0 is included in the range of the support?

Comment: Your definition of progressiveness implicitly requires such $f$ to be a function in the line “supported by  $[0,∞)$,” whereas [delta functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) are generalized functions instead of functions.

Comment: @Saad Note that the support of a distribution is also well-defined, though (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Support_of_a_distribution). Thus, in the context of Fourier theory, you could at the very least have a good notion of progressive tempered distribution.